# Using LINQ to convert a list to a CSV string

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a list of integers and I want to be able to convert this to a string where each number is separated by a comma.

So far example if my list was:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

My expected output would be:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Is this possible using LINQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In .NET 2/3

```
var csv = string.Join( ", ", list.Select( i => i.ToString() ).ToArray() );
```

or (in .NET 4.0)

```
var csv = string.Join( ", ", list );
```

Comment: Doesn’t work if `list` is a list of integers as specified in the question.

Comment: @Timwi - actually, it does in .NET 4, though, I forgot the fact that you no longer need an array, any enumerable will work.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you’re looking for?

```
// Can be int[], List<int>, IEnumerable<int>, ...
int[] myIntegerList = ...;

string myCSV = string.Join(", ", myIntegerList.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Starting with C# 4.0, the extra mumbojumbo is no longer necessary, it all works automatically:

```
// Can be int[], List<int>, IEnumerable<int>, ...
int[] myIntegerList = ...;

string myCSV = string.Join(", ", myIntegerList);
```

Comment: In fact, list should be `IEnumerable` because all other containers (you mentioned and not only they) inherits `IEnumerable` and `Select` is a method of `IEnumerable`

Comment: @abatishchev: The other containers *implement* `IEnumerable`, correct. The rest of what you said it wrong, especially the “list should be `IEnumerable`”, but also the “`Select` is a method of `IEnumerable`” (and even if you had said `IEnumerable<T>`, it would still be wrong). It’s an extension method.

Comment: Actually, even the select as string isn't necessary as `Join<T>( string, IEnumerable<T> )` will automatically convert each item in the enumerable to a string.

Comment: @Timwi: Yes, I mean `IEnumerable<T>` - omitted just for short. Extension methods can't be in the air, they should be linked to some class and `Select` is linked to `IEnumerable<T>` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx "Enumerable Methods"

Comment: @abatishchev: I know all that. But there’s an important difference between `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` and there’s an important difference between *“a method of `IEnumerable`”* (your wording) and an extension method.

Answer (score 2):

```
string csv = String.Join(", ", list.Select(i=> i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Technically, this answer does not produce the expected output as specified in the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(", ", list); //in .NET 4.0
```

and

```
String.Join(", ", list        
    .Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()) //in .NET 3.5 and below
```

Comment: your second statement makes no sense. it will give you a string array with one element.

Comment: @Scott had an extra parantheses from my testing, fixed.